# How do I add a parameter within a python function when using `**kwargs`

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have developed a function that takes a SQL query and runs it through big query from my python environment to pull the results back into said environment.

The function works great when I only want to filter my data to a particular country.  But how would I change the function when I want to add an additional filter?

My question is:

How do I add a variable set of parameters in order to dynamically filter the sql query?

Taking the below query:

```
price_query = """
      SELECT
      fcast_item
      ,hub_market_iso_cd
      ,Last_Day(Parse_Date('%Y%m%d', Concat(cast(year_month as string),"01")))
      ,dc_local

      FROM `gcp-vc-planning-prod.09_ingestion.pricing_exploded` 

      where hub_market_iso_cd = @country

      order by f`cast_item, year_month
      """
```

will return a data table filtered to a particular country.  If I want to dynamically add a filter, how would I do that?

The function as is:

```
def query_data(self, query, country_cd=None):
        query_ = query
        client = bigquery.Client("gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics")

        job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
                query_parameters=[
            bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("country_cd", "STRING", country_cd)]
            )

        query_job = client.query(
                query_,
                # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
                location="US",
                job_config=job_config
                )  # API request - starts the query

          df = query_job.to_dataframe()
          return df
```

The above works great if the only filter for the query is country_cd. But in the query, if I added `and fcast_item = @fcast_item` to the `WHERE` statement, how would I do that insde the function?

Basically, I would like to learn how to dynamically add the following line when more than one filter is added: `bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter("country_cd", "STRING", country_cd)]` where the three parameters inside the `ScalarQueryParameter` are able to be changed?

Answer (score 0):

I JUST FIGURED THIS OUT!  I have to iterate through the kwargs inside the function.

```
def query_data(self, query, **kwargs):
        query_ = query
        client = bigquery.Client("gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics")
        if kwargs != None:
            query_parameters = []
            for arg in kwargs.values():
                for i in arg:
                    query_parameters.append(bigquery.ScalarQueryParameter(i[0], i[1], i[2]))
            job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(
                    query_parameters=
                query_parameters
                )
            query_job = client.query(
                query_,
                # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
                location="US",
                job_config=job_config
                )  # API request - starts the query
            df = query_job.to_dataframe()
        else:
            query_job = client.query(
                query_,
                # Location must match that of the dataset(s) referenced in the query.
                location="US",
                )  # API request - starts the query
            df = query_job.to_dataframe()
        return df
```

Once the above function is in the environment, I can do the following.

`parameter_combo = [("country_cd", "STRING", country_cd), ("fcast_item", "STRING", fcast_item)]`
`price_df = query_data(query = price_query, parameter_combo = parameter_combo)`